# public address communicates to a private address over the internet problem

Tags: networking, communication

now i am running a network available bandwidth project.Suppose i am testing the **available bandwidth** between **my machine** and **planet1.scs.stanford.edu**.

Now the problem i am faced with is that my machine is using a **private address,say,172.18.186.200**,the other end is using a **public address,say 171.66.3.181**.Once i ran the test,the receiver end(*the remote machine assumed*) could not receive ACK from the sender end(*my local machine*).

i know my publicly routed address, i guess it is about the NAT.So how to correctly specify my local address to successfully carry out the testing project ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Which tool are you using? It seems a strange problem to have; if one peer can initiate a connection with the other peer, then you can measure the bandwidth between them.

Comment: @sarnold i am using pathchirp,here is the link http://www.spin.rice.edu/Software/pathChirp/

Comment: aha! That graphic describes it all. I'd suggest asking the software authors for help, I couldn't find anything in the source that looked helpful for instructing the sender when to start, and the code looks distinctly unloved. (If you can switch to a different tool, you might wish to do so.)

Comment: @sarnold actually i have sent an email to the author for help at the same i post this question.So aren't this a common problem ?

Comment: it's probably not _common_, in the sense that very few protocols support one machine telling a second machine to contact a third machine: `scp(1)` does support remote-to-remote copies, but I can't think of any other cases.

Comment: @ninjalj, ha! FTP surely is a _perfect_ counter-example to nearly any sweeping generality about protocols. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual form of NAT (masquerading) doesn't allow inbound connections. To allow them, you would need to add another form of NAT, port redirection, which in common ADSL routers tends to be called "Port Forwarding", "Virtual Servers", or something similar. This way, you tell your ADSL routers to forward connections to its port X to some internal IP on port Y.

(Some protocols use several connections, e.g: FTP, H.323, and send the information about secondary connections on the primary connection. These protocols need special support in the NAT device).